# b-prolog member function behaves suspiciously when using a list assigned to a variable

Tags: prolog

While interrogating b-prolog in the terminal, the member function does not seem to behave correctly when assigning a list to a variable and using the variable with the built in "member" function. I am having trouble interpreting the result when using a variable. Could anyone tell me if this is the correct behaviour and why it is the case?

```
B-Prolog Version 8.1, All rights reserved, (C) Afany Software 1994-2014.
| ?- List = [a,b,c,d].
List = [a,b,c,d]
yes
| ?- member(a,List).
List = [a|_14c] ?;
List = [_148,a|_154] ?;
List = [_148,_150,a|_15c] ?;
List = [_148,_150,_158,a|_164] ?;
List = [_148,_150,_158,_160,a|_16c] ?
yes

| ?- member(a,[a,b,c,d]).

yes
| ?-
```

I am using bprolog v 8.1 running on Windows 10 Pro (10.0.143393 Build 14393)

Comment: Top level request `member(a,List).` return all possible lists with member `a`.  It is correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-level queries are independent and don't share variables. If you try instead:

```
| ?- List = [a,b,c,d], member(a,List).
```

you will get the expected results.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but how do I interpret the result I see in the first call, it seems like it goes on infinitely, If List does not exist at the member call what are the responses with the strange list structure?

Comment: See Stanislav's comment. In other words, in that case, the `member/2` predicate acts like a *generator*. I.e. it generates lists with increasing length  that contain the atom `a`. You can see the results as list *templates*. Thus, for example, any list with a `a` in the first position is a solution. That list is represented by the term `[a| Tail]` where `Tail` can be any list. Note that all terms in the solutions that start with an underscore are variables.